# Sklearn Lasso Regression is orders of magnitude worse than Ridge Regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I've currently implemented Ridge and Lasso regression using the `sklearn.linear_model` module.

However, the Lasso Regression seems to do 3 orders of magnitude worse on the same dataset!

I'm not sure what's wrong, because mathematically, this shouldn't be happening. Here's my code:

```
def ridge_regression(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, model_alpha):
    clf = linear_model.Ridge(model_alpha)
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
    loss = np.sum((predictions - Y_test)**2)
    return loss

def lasso_regression(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, model_alpha):
    clf = linear_model.Lasso(model_alpha)
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
    loss = np.sum((predictions - Y_test)**2)
    return loss


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
for alpha in [0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
    print("Lasso loss for alpha=" + str(alpha) +": " + str(lasso_regression(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, alpha)))

for alpha in [1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 5, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    print("Ridge loss for alpha=" + str(alpha) +": " + str(ridge_regression(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, alpha)))
```

And here's my output:

```
Lasso loss for alpha=0: 20575.7121727
Lasso loss for alpha=0.01: 19762.8763969
Lasso loss for alpha=0.1: 17656.9926418
Lasso loss for alpha=0.5: 15699.2014387
Lasso loss for alpha=1: 15619.9772649
Lasso loss for alpha=2: 15490.0433166
Lasso loss for alpha=5: 15328.4303197
Lasso loss for alpha=10: 15328.4303197
Lasso loss for alpha=100: 15328.4303197
Lasso loss for alpha=1000: 15328.4303197
Lasso loss for alpha=10000: 15328.4303197
Ridge loss for alpha=1: 61.6235890425
Ridge loss for alpha=1.25: 61.6360790934
Ridge loss for alpha=1.5: 61.6496312133
Ridge loss for alpha=1.75: 61.6636076713
Ridge loss for alpha=2: 61.6776331539
Ridge loss for alpha=5: 61.8206621527
Ridge loss for alpha=10: 61.9883144732
Ridge loss for alpha=100: 63.9106882674
Ridge loss for alpha=1000: 69.3266510866
Ridge loss for alpha=10000: 82.0056669678
Ridge loss for alpha=100000: 88.4479064159
Ridge loss for alpha=1000000: 91.7235727543
```

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the data to make it reproducible?

Comment: Sure, http://ieor.berkeley.edu/~ieor265/homeworks/winequality-red.csv Y is the last column 'quality'. X is the first 11 rows.

Comment: I generated X and Y like so: `data = np.genfromtxt ('winequality-red.csv', delimiter=";")
data = data[1:,:]
X = data[:, :-1]
Y = data[:, -1:]`

Comment: I can definitely confirm that I'm seeing the same thing, and also that you get the same results from elastic net as from lasso, given the same alphas. It is strange. I wonder if maybe it's a characteristic of the data? Might be good to bring in CrossValidated to help with this.

Comment: Yep, testing with linear_model.MultiTaskLassoCV() gives MUCH more reasonable answers (loss of ~62).

Comment: so then it's gotta be that L2 regularization works but L1 doesn't, for this data? Ridge and MultiTaskLassoCV have L2 (the latter is L1/L2) but the other Lasso function was purely L1.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that L1 does not work well on this data? I'm inclined to agree, but the issue is that setting `alpha=0` for Lasso still has a huge loss (it should be close to OLS, which is also around ~62). Are there any other frameworks for Lasso? I couldn't find any

Comment: What you could do is use some elastic net where you can do a grid search on L1 and L2 values and see the loss as a gradient of values for different L1 and L2 parameters. Incidentally, running linear_model.MultiTaskElasticNetCV with the alphas from your lasso setup gives you a loss of 63.  I did notice that while the lasso model should theoretically give you OLS with alpha = 0 python/sklearn gives you a warning that it may not converge that way and that you should instead run the OLS function.

Comment: Good point. Still very confused about this behavior, but I did what you suggested. `clf = linear_model.MultiTaskElasticNetCV(1)` gives me an elastic net with l1_ratio of 1, which means my regularizer is strictly an L1 regularizer, correct? I do get the 63 loss I 'expect'.

Comment: Yea, alpha = 1 should be pure L1 (lasso) penalty. hmm

Comment: Well, I'm going to move on for now, thanks for all your help! Really appreciate it. If I have time, I'll circle back and try to figure out why it didn't work... :/

Answer (score 4):

Interesting problem. I can confirm that it's not an issue with the implementation of the algorithm, but the correct response to your input.

Here's a thought: you are not normalizing the data I believe from your description. This can lead to instability, as  your features have  significantly different orders of magnitude and variance. Lasso is more "all or nothing" than ridge (you've probably noticed it chooses many more 0 coefficients than ridge), so that instability is magnified.

Try to normalize your data, and see if you like your results better.

Another thought: that might be intentional from the Berkeley teachers, to highlight the fundamentally different behavior between ridge and lasso.